# Scikit-learn model representation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Suppose, i have some models created and fitted in `scikit-learn`.

```
model_rc = RidgeClassifier(class_weight='auto')
model_rc.fit(x_train, y_train)

model_dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model_dt.fit(x_train, y_train)

...
```

How can i get linear coefficients for `RidgeClassifier` or tree for `DecisionTree`.

In other words, I'm looking for `R` `summary` analogue in `scikit-learn`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a summary analog in sklearn, but you can get coefficients of ridge via `model_rc.coef_` and `model_rc.intercept_`, and you can seemingly get the tree via `model_dt.tree_`.

I have never tried to do anything with trees, so I don't know what you can do with that tree object. There is also a possibility to get its visual representation, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570042/visualizing-a-decision-tree-example-from-scikit-learn).